# Prioritize more than one EventHandler in C#.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eventhandler

So the problem is I have a class in C#, in Unity that has a few EventHandlers. They are responsible for input for GearVR but it's not relevant. I need to prioritize methods they're calling. I know that C# invokes them depending on order they're added. I know I can write a Dictionary that will handle that but then I'll need to write a lot of dictionaries (there's 16 events), and I also know I can override add funtion of these EventHandlers but it'll be a lot overriding.

I need to prioritize methods added to 16 events and I want to do it in a good way.Does anybody know how I can do such thing?

Comment: For traditional event programming, one should never plan on event handlers being called in any particular order, or give any priority to one handler over another.  If this is a requirement, an event system is not the correct pattern to use.

Comment: I agree with jdl134679. I gues the best you could do is to assign only one single method to the EventHandler, which calls the other methods in the order you want them to be called.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the problem is:

I have a script that allows player to teleport to the specific location he's looking when he touches GearVR touchpad. On the same touch he can release the object he's holding. I'm checking if he's looking at floor and if he is then I'm blocking the release of the object. Because Unity adds Teleportation script first then he's teleporting, then checking if he's looking at the floor. After teleportation often he isn't so he releases the object. That's why I need to prioritize wich touchpad prees invokes first, second etc.

Comment: And I'm using Event System because I can get rid of the Update() function that goes every frame and has only one Update in Input class that Invokes events than n Updates in every function that need to get an input.

Comment: Track your player state (e.g., where he's looking) outside the scope of the events, then refer to the state information from within the event handlers and act accordingly.  It's hard to say without knowing more of the project, but that seems like a more reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

We had that same issue recently in an HTC Vive Unreal project where a single input (trigger) was controlling various actions like:

- Moving a slider
- Teleporting freely
- Teleporting to a preset locations in an area
- etc...

In the end, and just as [jdl134679](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4155665/jdl134679) indicated, we used Tags on target objects to figure out what they user was pointing out (looking at in your case). In Unreal the PlayerController had the basic logic to handle a case or not.